# IllegalArgumentException since version 6.4.0.Final

Tags: java, optaplanner

Using a `List<Optional<PersoonFast>>` (where `PersoonFast` is a proper class) as `@ValueRangeProvider`, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entityClass (class nl.smartinstall.titania.solver.Bezetting) has a PlanningVariable annotated property (persoon) that refers to a ValueRangeProvider annotated member (field private java.util.List nl.smartinstall.titania.solver.PlanningDefault.personen) that returns a parameterized Collection with an unsupported type arguments (java.util.Optional&lt;nl.smartinstall.titania.solver.PersoonFast>).
```

Optaplanner version 6.3.0.Final accepts this construction and works fine, version 6.4.0.Final throws the exception. Could anyone please explain why the exception is thrown? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What's the method signature of `Bezetting.getPersoon()` and that of `PlanningDefault.getPersonen()`?

Comment: I 'll need more info to determine if this is a regression bug or not.

Comment: It is 'public Optional<PersoonFast> getPersoon()'.

There's no getter method 'PlanningDefault.getPersonen()'. Adding one ('    public List<Optional<PersoonFast>> getPersonen()') and moving the annotation from field to method results in a similar error (referring to the method).

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced it locally, this is [a confirmed bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-581) and fixed for `7.0.0.Beta1`.

That being said (OptaPlanner should support generic types as planning value classes) - **I advice against using `Optional` as a planning value class**, due to this warning from IntelliJ:

> Reports any uses of java.util.Optional, java.util.OptionalDouble,
>   java.util.OptionalInt, java.util.OptionalLong or
>   com.google.common.base.Optional as the type for a field or a
>   parameter. Optional was designed to provide a limited mechanism for
>   library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to
>   represent "no result". Using a field with type java.util.Optional is
>   also problematic if the class needs to be Serializable, which
>   java.util.Optional is not.